# Where are the Sitecore workflow comments stored?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, workflow

I am looking for the Sitecore path where the WorkFlow comments are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are not stored as Sitecore items - so there is no path.
If you want to get that data, you can find it in the SQL master database in the `WorkflowHistory` table.

In that table you can find:

- ItemID
- Language
- Version
- Old State / New State
- `Text`: here you will find the comments (json format)
- User
- Date